# Copy and Paste Between Applet and Other Applications

Tags: java, security, applet, copy-paste

I know there is a security policy restriction that does not allow cutting, copying, and pasting between an applet and some other application in the more recent versions of Java.  However, my users need this functionality.     Changing the java security policy file as defined here: 
https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/copy_and_paste_in_java

is impractical when dealing with a distributed application that is used by 100's of users.    So are there other alternatives that can be done in code?   This is a signed applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within a Java applet, even a signed one, I could not figure out how to access the system clipboard.   Statements like this:

Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

Actually freeze the applet making it impossible to continue.    This is using Java 1.8.

I read something here:

https://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/

That provided the basis for a work around.     Basically, you capture the selected text (assuming it is text that you want to move to the system clipboard) in java then make a call from within the applet to a Javascript method with the selected text as a parameter.   Javascript has built in methods that allow population of the system clipboard.   The details are in the link above.     Note, this was only tested with Internet Explorer 11.